# Including 0 in count does not work with extra where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

In my current project, I have user groups with facilities assigned to them. What I need is to show the **user group's name**, it's **department**, it's **description** and **number of facilities assigned** to it. I somewhat have been able to achieve this as shown below:

***Current "successful" result***

[image: Successful query of what I wanted]

The problem that I am facing now is when I add a where clause stating that facilities that have been deleted should **NOT** be included. Below is my SQL statement that produces the result above:

***Statement to achieve result above***

```
SELECT ug.usergroupname UserGroupName, dpt.deptname Department, ug.usergroupdesc UserGroupDesc, count(ugf.usergroupid) NumOFFacilities
FROM tblusergroup ug
LEFT JOIN tblusergroupfacilities ugf
ON ug.usergroupid = ugf.usergroupid
LEFT JOIN tbldepartment dpt
ON dpt.deptcode = ug.deptcode
LEFT JOIN tblfacility f
ON ugf.facilityid = f.facilityid
WHERE ug.isdeleted = 0
GROUP BY ug.usergroupname, dpt.deptname, ug.usergroupdesc
```

However, when I add the where clause to not include deleted facilities, it produces a whole other result:

***Edited statement***

```
SELECT ug.usergroupname UserGroupName, dpt.deptname Department, ug.usergroupdesc UserGroupDesc, count(ugf.usergroupid) NumOFFacilities
FROM tblusergroup ug
LEFT JOIN tblusergroupfacilities ugf
ON ug.usergroupid = ugf.usergroupid
LEFT JOIN tbldepartment dpt
ON dpt.deptcode = ug.deptcode
LEFT JOIN tblfacility f
ON ugf.facilityid = f.facilityid
WHERE ug.isdeleted = 0
AND f.isdeleted = 0     //<-------added clause
GROUP BY ug.usergroupname, dpt.deptname, ug.usergroupdesc
```

***Changed result***

[image]

Is there any way at all to achieve the results above excluding the deleted facilities? Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: A basic rule for adding conditions to outer joins: condition on outer table -> add to WHERE, condition on inner table -> add to ON: `LEFT JOIN tblfacility f
ON ugf.facilityid = f.facilityid
AND f.isdeleted = 0`

Comment: **Changed result** is current output, correct? Can you please confirm that, plus add desired result?

Comment: @dnoeth I tried this but it gives me the first output.

Comment: @KtX2SkD The number of facilities shown in the **Changed result ** are correct. I just need that and the other groups with 0 facilities in them.

Comment: @AdamLoh, thanks for clarifying, please don't forget to edit that into the question later.

Comment: Now I think I know what you want, you need to count a column which returns NULLs due to the outer join. In your 2nd query change the count to `count(f.facilityid)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing off the top of my head on how to do it in one query, but with a `UNION` it seems straightforward. Run each alone to understand what they provide:

```
-- Your "changed" query.

UNION -- or UNION ALL, look up the difference, cuz I forgot it.

-- Your original query.
HAVING count(ugf.usergroupid) = 0
```

Comment: Mate I don't know how that works..but it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A `LEFT JOIN` keeps all rows in the first table plus matching rows in the second.  When there is no match, then the values returned are `NULL`.  Your condition on `f.isdeleted` removes all `NULL` values, turning the `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`.

The solution is to put the condition in the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT ug.usergroupname UserGroupName, dpt.deptname Department, ug.usergroupdesc UserGroupDesc, count(ugf.usergroupid) NumOFFacilities
FROM tblusergroup ug LEFT JOIN
     tblusergroupfacilities ugf
     ON ug.usergroupid = ugf.usergroupid LEFT JOIN
     tbldepartment dpt
     ON dpt.deptcode = ug.deptcode LEFT JOIN
     tblfacility f
     ON ugf.facilityid = f.facilityid AND f.isdeleted = 0
WHERE ug.isdeleted = 0
GROUP BY ug.usergroupname, dpt.deptname, ug.usergroupdesc;
```

Note that conditions on the first table do belong in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: I tried your code but it's giving me the same result as the "Current Successful Result".The thing is, record number 4 should only have 1 facilities. The number of facilities shown in the second output is the one I need INCLUDING groups that have 0 facilities in them.